# Mysql and php database

Tags: php, mysql

I am kind of new to php to mysql

I have to find a user with only a userid so i need to find out usernames emails from my mysql datebase 
db name users

Comment: I guess I am not sure exactly what you are asking help on.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Please give us table definitions and explain what you really need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$user_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username,email FROM users WHERE userid='"$user_id"'");

Comment: so i kinda need to get a username, Email from my database were i only have a user id...                                                                         So i have a data base like so         Userid         username     Email              password         1               Ryan       Ryan@ryan.com      ****

Comment: oh and also im going to use this code                                   0 down vote accept
 

$user_id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT username,email FROM users WHERE userid='"$user_id"'");
                                                                            and how do u get the username and email values out if the database query

Comment: Ok i have just tried it on my website and it has came out with resource id#7 and resource id#7 and it will not display the name or Email?  I have user this code....        $user_id= $_GET['id']; 
$fullname = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`='$user_id'");
$email = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `Email` FROM `users` WHERE `userid`='$user_id'");

Answer (score 8):

Re your specific question, you probably need something like:

```
$id = (int) $id;
mysql_query("select users.* from users where users.userid = $id;");
```

There's a php tutorial here:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

A MySQL tutorial here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tutorial.html

And an even better PostgreSQL tutorial here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial.html